# Use Jquery Validation Plugin to add real-time validations to my form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to validate my form in real-time (on input) using this jquery plugin : https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/?

This is an example of my current validation function:

```
(function(ns, window, document, $, undefined) {

var $form;

ns.init= function(){

    $form = $('#formQA');

    $form.validate({
        rules : {
            QResponse : {
                required: function (element) {
                    if ($(element).is(":visible")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                } ,
                maxlength: 255,
                minlength: 2
            }
        }
    })
}
})(home.createNS('home.qa.validation', false), window, document, jQuery);
```

Comment: What is the question here? Is the validation not working?

Comment: no it works but I want it be , real-time : while I am typing and not when I move to another input field

Comment: How do you plan on doing that? How do you plan to validate something that is not completed? What are you testing it against?

Comment: You could bind a key up listener on the input to fire your validation function with each key press.

Comment: Or you could override the `onkeyup` option with: `onkeyup: function(element) { this.element(element) }`

Comment: jQuery Form Validator is not the same plugin.  Please do not tag-spam.  Edited.

Answer (score 2):

By default, it validates on the `keyup` event.  However, validation is "lazy", not "eager", which means that no validation happens until after the first click of submit.  So you'll have to tweak some settings.

```
$form.validate({
    rules : {
        // rules
    },
    onfocusout: function(element) {
        this.element(element); // triggers validation
    },
    onkeyup: function(element, event) {
        this.element(element); // triggers validation
    }
});
```

---

Your code:

```
required: function (element) {
    if ($(element).is(":visible")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You do not need to test for visibility.  By default, the plugin will dynamically ignore any hidden field.  Just set `required` to `true` and let the rest happen.