# jquery validation real time

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validation plugin for validating my forms
https://jqueryvalidation.org/

I need to have eager validation, for that I've used from this post
[Use Jquery Validation Plugin to add real-time validations to my form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45821997/use-jquery-validation-plugin-to-add-real-time-validations-to-my-form/45845857?noredirect=1#comment86836631_45845857)

Now I have it working with eager validation.

But I have issue with displaying the error message too early.

I have a text box that requires at least 10 characters.
As soon as user starts typing he gets a validation error. But I need to show the error message only when it's less than 10 chars and it's blur and not from start when user starts typing.
But I still need to get success when user keyup 10 chars.

So, when we have

Keyup

- the error message shouldn't be shown (now this is not working so)
- I need to have success as soon as 10 chars are typed (now it works so)

Blur

- if 10 chars aren't filled user should get the error message

Here's my code
https://jsfiddle.net/k8213c41/13/

```
<form id="postForm" action="">
   <div>Minimum of 10 characters</div>
   <textarea id="description" rows="10" cols="50" name="description" ></textarea>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#postForm").validate({
            rules: {
                description: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10
                }
            },
            onfocusout: function(element) {
                this.element(element); // triggers validation
            },
            onkeyup: function(element, event) {
                this.element(element); // triggers validation
            },
            messages: {
                description: {
                    required: "Please enter your description",
                    minlength: "Description requires at least 10 characters"
                }
            },
            errorElement: "div"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Plugin is "lazy" (validation) by default.  You want "eager" validation.  Click on duplicate(s) above for answer.

Comment: Thanks for info, that was helpful. I checked these links and added blur and keyup. But now on keyup I get a validation error before it's filled correctly. Is there any way to see the validation error only when it's blur and have success during keyup? Here's my updated code
https://jsfiddle.net/k8213c41/13/

Comment: How can you expect it to show success when less than 10 characters is a validation failure?

Comment: @Sparky I've edited my question, I've described the issue what I have and how I need to work. Thanks